# Who and what to grant to allow Azure DevOps to grant application role to new Azure Container Environment App created via Bicep script

Tags: azure-devops, azure-bicep, azure-rbac, azure-container-apps

Good day,

We are struggling horribly with our infrastructure-as-code journey. We have set up an Azure Container Apps environment and written a bicep script which sets up all needed resource (app with managed identity, key vault, app registration, etc) which all works fine. Problem is, the new app's managed identity needs to be granted a custom role in an Enterprise App, let's call it ExternalAPIProxy.

Granting custom roles is not something which is possible directly via Bicep, it seems, so we have added a step to run an azure client command in order to grant the role. And this is where things have come to an abrupt stop. We seems to be completely unable to set up the DevOps Service Principal running the script correctly in order to grant the role (this is one of many attempts, some involving PowerShell, but all lead to the same issue):

az rest 
--method POST 
--uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/$managedIdentity/appRoleAssignments" 
--headers 'Content-Type=application/json' 
--body "{"principalId": "$managedIdentity", "resourceId": "$externalApiProxyId"}"

This leads to an error:

Forbidden({"error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.","innerError":{"date":"2024-02-07T13:42:38","request-id":"3a5d779a-3243-4684-9058-c3002837016f","client-request-id":"3a5d779a-3243-4684-9058-c3002837016f"}}})

Which role assignment does the service principal need to be able to grant a custom role? Is there a better way to do this?

We have tried many different ways of adding the role, but seem to get stuck on more or less the same step - which service/identity/user needs what kind of permission to grant custom application roles to the newly created app in azure container service? Fwiw, it's a bog standard .net rest API being deployed, but I do not think that's important in this context.

Comment: Try assigning Application Administrator role to the user who is performing the action and check if that works

Comment: At what level would I need to add that role, @Rukmini? I cannot seem to comprehend where App registrations are located in the roles levels. Since they are accessible across Subscriptions, I assume it won't help to add them at a specific subscripion level?

Comment: Try to add role to the user in the subscription level where the managed identity is present

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a Service Principal as authorization to run the related command lines to assign custom role to a managed identity on an enterprise app, the Service Principal should have the **Privileged Role Administrator** or **Global Administrator** role at the Azure AD (Microsoft Entra ID) level.

[image]

For more details, see the following documentation:

- [**Create custom roles to manage enterprise apps in Microsoft Entra ID**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/role-based-access-control/custom-enterprise-apps)
- [**Assign Microsoft Entra roles to users**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/role-based-access-control/manage-roles-portal)

---

Comment: This might work, but it seemed to be enough with the Application Administrator role :-)

Answer (score 0):

The comments by Rukmini allowed us to solve this, finally.

The Service Principal set up by/via Azure Devops to perform the release needed to be set up as ApplicationAdministrator in Azure Entra Id. Getting the correct Id was surprisingly hard, but the easiest way I found was to do use PowerShell

```
Get-MgServicePrincipalByAppId -AppId <appId found in the app registration overview page>
```

Once we had the Id, a quick id search in Entra Id lead to the correct service principal, which was then granted the Application Administrator role.

When the correct role was granted, this section of our deployment script worked flawlessly:

```
hasAccess=$(az rest \
    --method GET \
    --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/$managedIdentity/appRoleAssignments" \
    | jq ".value|any(.resourceId == \"$externalApiProxyResourceId\" and .principalId == \"$managedIdentity\")") \
    || { echo "Failed check for role assignment. Stopping..."; exit 3; }

if [[ "$hasAccess" == "true" ]]; then
    echo "App has role assignment. Skipping."
else
    echo "Assigning app role assignment to app"
    az rest \
        --method POST \
        --uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/$managedIdentity/appRoleAssignments" \
        --headers 'Content-Type=application/json' \
        --body "{\"principalId\": \"$managedIdentity\", \"resourceId\": \"$exerpProxyResourceId\"}"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: To assign app roles to the service principal, the user performing the action must be assigned Application Administrator or Privileged Role Administrator role or any one of the roles mentioned in this  [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

Initially I got the **same error** as below:(*For sample, I executed the command in bash*)

*For sample:*

```bash
az rest --method POST --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/ManagedIdentityId/appRoleAssignments" --headers "Content-Type=application/json" --body "{\"principalId\": \"PrincipalID\", \"resourceId\": \"ResourceID\", \"appRoleId\": \"AppRoleID\"}"
```

[image]

**Hence to resolve the error,** I assigned the user with Application Administrator active role like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Microsoft Entra roles and administrators -> Click on Application Administrator -> Assign*

[image]

[image]

*It takes few minutes to reflect the role to the user, wait for around ~20 mins and login again to perform the task.*

After assigning the role, **the user is able to assign app role to the managed identity successfully**:

[image]

If you are using Service Principal then assign role to the application.